# Javascript Variables Not Defined Within iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm working with a webpage that has a modal iFrame that pops up after clicking a link on the page. Within that iFrame, I need info that was defined on the parent/main page.

I've defined the variables I'm interested in globally as such:

`window.myVar = myVar;`

But within the iFrame, when I attempt to access that variable by calling `top.myVar` or parent.myVar I get an error in the console:

`Error: Permission denied to access property 'myVar'`

Any ideas on what I might be running into?

Comment: Learn about the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Comment: Hmm, so this applies even if it's the same domain with different protocols then. Any way around this or does my iFrame have to be loaded insecurely?

Comment: Right there in the chart `https://store.company.com/secure.html Failure Different protocol`

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the code of both pages and is it on the same domain?
**If yes**, add the following script in both page:

```
<script>
    document.domain = 'yourDomain.com';
</script>
```

Than you should have access to 'myVar'.